# How to maximize re usability in three separate projects with a lot of shared stuff?

Tags: android, architecture

Suppose we have three different ***android applications*** that 80% of logic and UI is shared among them:

`App1`, `App2`, `App3`

I tend to reuse the shared UI and code as much as I can. But minor differences between the data models, logic and UI prevent us from 100% reuse the components and functionalities.

Suppose we have a login process in all applications that basically are the same in all three applications though there are some changes.
For example in all applications `username` and `password` are needed to login. and the result of the login method is a `User` class in case of success and null in case of failure. Considering the differences between applications, In `App2` we have a login form with an extra field named "ServerAddress". While another difference is in the `App3`, which we have to run an extra step in login process in. To complicate the problem a little more, suppose that `User` class in `App1` has an extra property named `DateCreated`.

At first glance it may seem too simple to overcome this issue. You may suggest me declaring a base class `User` and a child class `ReportedUser` specially for `App1`. In this case it could be solved this simple but for other issues it is more complicated. ***for example the differences in sqlite database and xml layouts can not be overridden by OOP!*** What Should I do in this regard?

- What is the best way to handle this inconsistency?
- Is this related to `software architecture`?
- What are the technologies that I should be aware to work in this
  context?
- Are `AOP` or `IoC` related to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a [library](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html) (that will contain the core of all the apps), and try to replace the SQL with [Realm](https://realm.io/news/realm-for-android/) which is easier to use it this cases.

And if you have a **User** in your core library, you can create a child named **ReportedUser** and Realm will handle it with ease.